# summarizing counts of a factor with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to group a data frame by a column (owner) and output a new data frame that has counts of each type of a factor at each observation. The real data frame is fairly large, and there are 10 different factors.

Here is some example input:

```
library(dplyr)
df = tbl_df(data.frame(owner=c(0,0,1,1), obs1=c("quiet", "loud", "quiet", "loud"), obs2=c("loud", "loud", "quiet", "quiet")))

  owner  obs1  obs2
1     0 quiet  loud
2     0  loud  loud
3     1 quiet quiet
4     1  loud quiet
```

I was looking for output that looks like this:

```
out = data.frame(owner=c("0", "0", "1", "1"), observation=c("obs1", "obs2", "obs1", "obs2"), quiet=c(1, 0, 1, 2), loud=c(1, 2, 1, 0))

  owner observation quiet loud
1     0        obs1     1    1
2     0        obs2     0    2
3     1        obs1     1    1
4     1        obs2     2    0
```

Melting gets me partway there:

```
melted = tbl_df(melt(df, id=c("owner")))

  owner variable value
1     0     obs1 quiet
2     0     obs1  loud
3     1     obs1 quiet
4     1     obs1  loud
5     0     obs2  loud
6     0     obs2  loud
7     1     obs2 quiet
8     1     obs2 quiet
```

But what's the last step? If 'value' was a numeric, I'd just go:

```
melted %>% group_by(owner, variable) %>% summarise(counts=sum(value))
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: This is an old question, but for what it's worth there's a little-known feature of `dcast` that allows you to apply an aggregating/summary function in these cases. I think it defaults to counting.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In 2017 the answer is

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gather(df, key, value, -owner) %>%
  group_by(owner, key, value) %>%
  tally %>% 
  spread(value, n, fill = 0)
```

Which gives output

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: owner, key [4]

  owner   key  loud quiet
* <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0  obs1     1     1
2     0  obs2     2     0
3     1  obs1     1     1
4     1  obs2     0     2
```

In 2019 the answer is:

```
gather(df, key, value, -owner) %>% 
    count(owner, key, value) %>% 
    spread(value, n, fill = 0)
```

Comment: This is the better answer these days.

Comment: In 2019 the answer is

````
    gather(df, key, value, -owner) %>%
        count(owner, key, value) %>%
        spread(value, n, fill = 0)
````

Comment: in 2019 is pivot_longer / wider recommended over gather / spread?

Comment: @baxx [It seems so](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) (I had to look up gather to remind myself what it is).

Answer (score 29):

You could use `tidyr` with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

 df %>%
 gather(observation, Val, obs1:obs2) %>% 
 group_by(owner,observation, Val) %>% 
 summarise(n= n()) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 spread(Val, n, fill=0)
```

which gives the output

```
  #    owner observation loud quiet
  #1     0        obs1    1     1
  #2     0        obs2    2     0
  #3     1        obs1    1     1
  #4     1        obs2    0     2
```

Comment: `df %>% gather(observation, Val, obs1:obs2) %>% group_by(owner, variable, value) %>% summarise(n= n()) %>% spread(value, n, fill=0)`

Comment: @Rory Kirchner The column names should be consistent.  Here, in the `gather(...)` you created a variable `Val`, but in the `group_by(...)` and later on that variable was discarded and in its places `value` was used.

Comment: Hm-- Val -> value for me:

 df %>% gather(observation, Val, obs1:obs2) ->   owner variable value as the column names

Comment: I'm getting "index out of bounds" error with your `spread` approach.

Comment: @Paulo Cardoso  It did work with the version I had before.  Now, it seems like you have to do `ungroup()` before `spread` as Val` is one of the `grouping` variable.

Comment: True. Thank you for updating your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to forego the `dplyr`, you can split into lists.

```
df <- split(df, list(df[[obs1]], df[[obs2]])
```

If you wanted the `count`, you just create an `sapply` or `lapply` call to run through the lists and get the count of each one. Or literally any other function you want.