# dplyr: put count occurrences into new variable

Tags: r, dplyr

Would like to get a hand on dplyr code, but cannot figure this out. Have seen a similar issue described here for many variables ([summarizing counts of a factor with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811756/summarizing-counts-of-a-factor-with-dplyr) and [Putting rowwise counts of value occurences into new variables, how to do that in R with dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838322/putting-rowwise-counts-of-value-occurences-into-new-variables-how-to-do-that-in)), however my task is somewhat smaller.
Given a data frame, how do I count the frequency of a variable and place that in a new variable.

```
set.seed(9)
df <- data.frame(
    group=c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),
    var1=round(runif(10,1,3),0))
```

Then we have:

```
>df
   group var1
1      1    1
2      1    1
3      1    1
4      1    1
5      1    2
6      2    1
7      2    2
8      2    2
9      2    2
10     2    3
```

Would like a third column indicating per-group (`group`) how many times `var1` occurs, in this example this would be: count=(4,4,4,4,1,1,3,3,3,1).
I tried - without success - things like:

```
df %>%  group_by(group) %>% rowwise() %>% do(count = nrow(.$var1))
```

Explanations are very appreciated!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

All you need to do is group your data by both columns, "group" and "var1":

```
df %>% group_by(group, var1) %>% mutate(count = n())
#Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
#Groups: group, var1
#
#   group var1 count
#1      1    1     4
#2      1    1     4
#3      1    1     4
#4      1    1     4
#5      1    2     1
#6      2    1     1
#7      2    2     3
#8      2    2     3
#9      2    2     3
#10     2    3     1
```

#### Edit after comment

Here's an example of how you SHOULD NOT DO IT:

```
df %>% group_by(group, var1) %>% do(data.frame(., count = length(.$group)))
```

The dplyr implementation with `n()` is for sure much faster, cleaner and shorter and should always be preferred over such implementations as above.

Comment: Nice @beginneR! So if I had more columns like ID, name whatever, I should still only group the two I am interested in ?

Comment: @user3375672, If you had another grouping variable in addition to the existing two ("group" and "var1"), called "ID" for example, you would group your data by those three columns and then use mutate and n() like in my answer.

Comment: Still, I don't get it, why I cannot replace nrow() instead of the n() function from dplyr

Comment: Well, that is mainly because you are using dplyr which has a number of special functions designed to work with dplyr's syntax and `n()` is one of them. Technically, you could use the base R function `nrow()` in a `do()` statement in dplyr BUT that would make any sense because dplyr's special functions make your life so much easier.

Comment: If you have **lots of data**, this command is SUPERFAST

Answer (score 30):

Perhaps this is new functionality, but it can be done with one `dplyr` command:

```
df %>% add_count(group, var1)
   group  var1     n
 1     1     1     4
 2     1     1     4
 3     1     1     4
 4     1     1     4
 5     1     2     1
 6     2     1     1
 7     2     2     3
 8     2     2     3
 9     2     2     3
10     2     3     1
```

Comment: If you have **lots of data**, this command is SUPERFAST

Answer (score 11):

We may use probably another handy function `tally` from `dplyr`

```
df %>% group_by(group, var1) %>% tally()
# Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
# Groups: group
# 
#   group var1 n
# 1     1    1 4
# 2     1    2 1
# 3     2    1 1
# 4     2    2 3
# 5     2    3 1
```

Comment: If that was the desired result (which it is not, according to the question) you could even just use `df %>% count(group, var1)`.

Comment: @beginneR, Yep, depends on how we understand the required format of output. This looks more terse since it only shows the unique pairs.

Comment: I agree, after reading the Q again, that it's not 100% clear.. Anyway, it's a good option to consider.

Comment: I agree to! So the answer from beginneR was what I had in mind, i.e. to add the results to the data frame structure keeping the number of rows.

Comment: I am using this solution, however I need to put the results back in my long-format dataframe. Can anybody tell me how do I do that?

Answer (score 9):

Two alternatives:

**1:** with base R:

```
# option 1:
df$count <- ave(df$var1, df$var1, df$group, FUN = length)
# option 2:
df <- transform(df, count = ave(var1, var1, group, FUN = length))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>    group var1 count
> 1      1    1     4
> 2      1    1     4
> 3      1    1     4
> 4      1    1     4
> 5      1    2     1
> 6      2    1     1
> 7      2    2     3
> 8      2    2     3
> 9      2    2     3
> 10     2    3     1
> ```

**2:** with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, count := .N, by = .(group, var1)]
```

which gives the same result:

> ```
> > df
>     group var1 count
>  1:     1    1     4
>  2:     1    1     4
>  3:     1    1     4
>  4:     1    1     4
>  5:     1    2     1
>  6:     2    1     1
>  7:     2    2     3
>  8:     2    2     3
>  9:     2    2     3
> 10:     2    3     1
> ```

---

If you want to summarise, you can use:

```
# with base R:
aggregate(id ~ group + var1, transform(df, id = 1), length)

# with 'dplyr':
count(df, group, var1)

# with 'data.table':
setDT(df)[, .N, by = .(group, var1)]
```

Comment: Can't understand why `df$count <- ave(df$var1, df$group, FUN = length)` does not work. Why need to specify `var1` twice?

Comment: If you have **lots of data**, this command is SUPER SLOW. Prefer the others.

Comment: RE 1st comment: The first `var1` is the input for the lengt-function, the 2nd `var1` is used as a grouping variable (together with `group`). RE 2nd comment: If you have lots of data, use the [tag:data.table] option; its the fastest available in the R ecosystem.

Comment: @luchonacho the data.table option is the fastest one.